# Convergence of a logarithmic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, logarithms

Is this series $\sum\limits_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\log(1+x)}$ convergent or divergent?

If it were only $\sum\limits_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\log(x)}$, then I could use Cauchy condensation formula.

But now I'm stuck with it.

Comment: For large $x$, both series behave equivalently.

Comment: How about 1/log^2(x+1)

Comment: Also diverging, like any power.

Comment: ^Can you tell me how to prove it? Limit comparison test/basic comparison tests don't work here.

Answer (score 4):

Note that you can easily find a $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $n > \log(1+n)$ so $\frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{\log (1+n)}$.

Now, you know that the harmonic series diverges, so by comparison, the sum stated diverges.

Comment: Yes I had looked upon that but to use limit comparison test  lim n/log(1+n) must be finite and non zero.

Comment: Not the limit comparison test, the [regular old comparison test](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/SeriesCompTest.aspx): if $a_n, b_n>0$, and $a_n > b_n$ and $\sum_n a_n$ is convergent, then $\sum_n b_n$ is convergent. If $a_n < b_n$ and $\sum_n a_n$ is divergent, $\sum_n b_n$ is divergent.

Answer (score 3):

Notice when we write

$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\log (1+x)} = \frac{1}{\log 2} + \frac{1}{\log 3} + \frac{1}{\log 4} + \cdots$$

your sum looks exactly like $\sum_{x=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\log x}$. You are allowed to reindex your sum by picking a new dummy variable, such as $y = 1+x$. To figure out your new lower bound, you simply plug in $x=1$ to get $y=2$, and similarly for your upper bound. Now you can apply the Cauchy condensation test as originally desired.